# Avoid file overwrites in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ide

I love Netbeans, but there's a "bug" or "way of doing things" that I don't like, and I want to know if there's something I could do to make it right:

Scenario

1. I edit a example.css in Netbeans & save.
2. I edit example.css outside Netbeans & save.
3. I edit example.css in Netbeans again.

Problem: Changes in #2 were overwritten.

Do you know how to config Netbeans to check for updates on files before save?

Do you know a similar IDE for PHP that works with remote project similar to Netbeans?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NetBeans: I think you should perform `Source -> Scan for external` before saving.

I believe this feature(`Auto Refresh`) is supported by by `Eclipse` new versions. If you want to switch your IDE, please download from here-->[**Eclipse for PHP Developers**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/heliosr).

You may find steps to configure `Eclipse` with remote file system, please refer [**Getting Started with the Remote System Explorer**](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fg_start.html).

Comment: Eclipse is an option I will try soon. I'm not sure if your suggestion about Netbeans does check for remote changes... This is the option by default and I had overwritten files often.

Comment: I meant to `execute that option each time` before saving.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I'll try it. Shame on Netbeans!